# Characterization of formally étale morphisms between microlinear objects?

Tags: synthetic-differential

The following is taken from [Penon's thesis](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/DIA/DIA_1985__S13_/DIA_1985__S13__1_0/DIA_1985__S13__1_0.pdf), (d) at the top of page 44. Can anybody explain how to prove this?

> Let $f:M\to N$ be an arrow of microlinear objects. Then the square
>   below is a pullback iff $\operatorname{d}_x\!f:T_xM\to T_{fx}N$ is a
>   bijection for all $x\in M$.
>
> $$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} TM @>{df}>> TN\\ @VVV @VVV\\ M @>>{f}> N
>  \end{CD}$$
>
> This is also equivalent if we replace tangent bundles by the
>   exponential objects $M^{J_1},N^{J_2}$ where each $J$ is of the form
>   $D^{(n_1)}\times \cdots \times D^{(n_k)}$, where $$D^{(n)}= \left\{
>  (x_1,\dots ,x_n)\in R^n \mid x_i\cdot x_j=0\forall i,j \right\}.$$